# How can I create valid reference without checking sy-subrc?

Tags: reference, abap

In this READ statement if there is no row in the table I have a dump.

```
read table it_example reference into data(lr_example) with key matnr = '22000000'.
```

This happened also with `OPTIONAL` statement.

```
DATA(ls_konp) = REF #( lt_konp[ knumh = <fs_a305>-knumh ] OPTIONAL ).
```

How can I use reference without checking `sy-subrc`? I often use this inline declaration for table in select statement.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please post the information about the dump? In your second example there is no reference at all, because you use `VALUE`.

Comment: I update the question. In the second case i used REF #, sorry

Comment: Can you not use IS BOUND check before accessing the referenced variable ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DATA(ls_konp) = REF #( lt_konp[ knumh = <fs_a305>-knumh ] DEFAULT NEW konp( ) ).
```

Prefer this method if your code is perfectly fine with the situation that ls_konp might be an empty line.

Answer (score 4):

```
TRY.
    DATA(ls_konp) = REF #( lt_konp[ knumh = <fs_a305>-knumh ] ).
    ls_konp->...
    " in this block, ignore that ls_konp might not be BOUND
  CATCH cx_sy_itab_line_not_found.
    " in this block, focus exclusively on the case ls_konp IS NOT BOUND
ENDTRY.
```

Prefer this method if you need to explicitly handle the case where ls_konp is not bound.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are dereferencing a non initialised reference. If you do not want to use `sy-subrc` then do it with [`IF lr_example IS BOUND.`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-us/abenlogexp_bound.htm) and first then try to dereference your object.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a fake empty reference and use **DEFAULT** predicate of a `REF` statement for making a reference never initial.

```
DATA: ls_konp TYPE konp.

DATA(ref) = REF #( ls_konp ).

DATA(lr_konp) = REF #( lt_konp[ knumh = <fs_a305>-knumh ] DEFAULT ref ).
```